# Blackberry XYEdges class explanation

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, location

Ok, I've read through [the documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/XYEdges.html) for information concerning how the XYEdges class works, but I seem to be misunderstanding something. My question is where is the point of origin on this coordinate system? Is (0,0,0,0) located at the top left corner perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no coordinate system for XYEdges.  You explicitly define top, right, bottom and left (which are relative to the Screen) instead of defining x, y, width and height. So, (0, 0, 0, 0) would be an empty edge region in the top left.